# Is it possible to use DispatcherServlet as fallback when using Jersey starter in Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to have Jersey application on `/` but still allow `DispatcherServlet` to serve static content (eg from `classpath:/whatever/path/here/`) as a fallback?

I have tried to map `DispatcherServlet` to `/` and use `JersetContainer` (or something like that) to act as Filter instead of Servlet, however Jersey fallsback to default container servlet implementation which is `DefaultServlet` in my case.

So is it possible to have Jersey as a filter on the same mapping path with `DispatcherServlet` ??

Comment: Have you configured Jersey to forward to the next filter in the chain when it doesn’t find a resource that matches the request?

Comment: Its called something like FORWARD_ON_404 or something similar right? Yep its set to true, but it is forwarded to different servlet, not to `DispatcherServlet` So basicly yes, it is forwarded to servled, but not the right one

Comment: Then the dispatcher servlet isn’t mapped properly as there’s only a single servlet at the end of the chain. Perhaps you could update your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: That is the point. Idk how to propertly map that servlet to be used instead of Catalina's default implementation. Will try to organize MCVE

Comment: It seems like I cannot reproduce this issue on clean project - even with `exclude=WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class` servlet provided to Catalinas `ApplicationFilterChain` is `DispatcherServlet`. I cannot share the actual code whatsoever;/ Do you have any ideas what could tweak servlet container to use `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` instead DispacherServlet in spring boot env?